# C# Non-generic method in generic class

Tags: c#, generics

Am trying to define a class that provides a random number between two values. It shall work with ints as well as with floats.

To only have a single class, I'd like to use generics.
This works well for the member variables, but how do I define a method for only specific types?

The Random.Range method I use (from unity) can accept floats or ints so a cast is needed. The generic type does not seem to be castable at all however.

Have written this code to show what I am looking for. Does a syntax similar to this exist?

```
public class MinMaxSetting<T>
{
    public T min;
    public T max;

    public MinMaxSetting(T min_val, T max_val)
    {
        min = min_val;
        max = max_val;
    }

    public T GetRandom<int>()
    {
        return Random.Range((int)min, (int)max);
    }
    public T GetRandom<float>()
    {
        return Random.Range((float)min, (float)max);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would think you'd want `public T GetRandom<T>()`, where `T` is either `int` or `float`...

Comment: this is overkill just create 2 explicit methods, no generics

Comment: problem here is that you can only support int or float and there is no where clause you can add that says that I dont think

Comment: What's the end result here? You're either calling `Random.Range(int, int)` or `Random.Range(float, float)`. You'll have to pick between these methods somewhere. Generics can't help you with that.

Comment: @pm100 Yes exactly that's the issue unfortunately. It wouldn't suffice to have two methods, it'd have to be two separate classes.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Well, is there a way to pick? Something like "if (T == int)" does obviously not exist and the members are not castable anyways.

Comment: `typeof(T) == typeof(int)` does exist but wont help you. Unless you constrain to numerics you class wont compile

Comment: @pm100 it's overkill to even put a wrapper around Random.Next

Comment: @pm100 This does have a purpose. It's all for an Unity class where I can attach a PopertyDrawer to the class to show the min and max options in the editor. For the moment I've ended up just defining two separate classes.

Comment: You could take a constructor argument `Func<T,T,T>` to push the problem to the caller or factory method.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Your comment reminded me of extension methods - those resulted in a nifty solution, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: Extension Methods!
Surely a bit quirky but it does what it's supposed to and it's readable.

```
public class MinMaxSetting<T>
{
    public T min;
    public T max;

    public MinMaxSetting(T min_val, T max_val)
    {
        min = min_val;
        max = max_val;
    }
}

// Helper class just for the extension methods. The name is irrelevant.
public static class MinMaxSetting
{
    public static float GetRandom(this MinMaxSetting<float> self)
    {
        return UnityEngine.Random.Range(self.min, self.max);
    }
    public static int GetRandom(this MinMaxSetting<int> self)
    {
        return UnityEngine.Random.Range(self.min, self.max);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    MinMaxSetting<float> my_setting = new MinMaxSetting<float>(5.3f, 20.4f);
    Console.WriteLine(my_setting.GetRandom());
}
```